# How to display a ul list from left using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On mouseover of Diveagar category one drop down list is displayed but it displays from that div only.

I want to display it from left Ex: from "Quick look" tab, I have used the following code to display the div when mouse is over.

```html
<ul  class="nav pull-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <p> 
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " style="color:black;" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $sub_desti_res["sub_destination"]; ?><br> 2 Packages Available
     </a>
       </p>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>     
           <div class="destination-list">
              <div class="col-md-12">
```

[image: Example Image]

Comment: The irony is that you have tagged it as CSS and there's no CSS code given here. LoL.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.menu {display: block; text-align: center;}
.menu a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; }
.menu > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 100px;}
.menu ul {position: absolute; width: 150px; left: -25px; display: none;}
.menu > li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 5</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no sir when mouse is over on that particular div i want that listed div in center of that hover div

Comment: @Vivek You didn't say that should be centred. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Vivek Check the updated answer please? And please don't call *sir*.

Comment: now it will display from hovered div i want to display it from "divegar 2 deals available " div is there at first no i want to display it from here .please hlp me sir .

Comment: @Vivek Did you see the updated one? Clarify again na? Coz I am still unable to understand. Can you draw a pic and tell what you wanna achieve? And again, please don't call *sir*.

Comment: no second also not working . i just want to display the list of available deals  in div when mouse is over but that list is displayed from that particular div only thing is that i want to start the display the deals list from left

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106445/discussion-between-vivek-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Put this CSS style:

```
.nav {position: relative;}
.dropdown-menu {position:absolute;left:0;width:100%;}
```

Comment: This is not the OP Wants.